# JQuery in New Google Sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, google-sites

I'm painfully new to any coding beyond VBA, and I'm sure it shows! I'm stuck, and I think I'm missing something obvious.

**What I'm trying to do:** This code will be embedded in a New Google Sites page (yeah, very limiting). It shows a bunch of checkboxes; users choose one or more options, then click a button. Clicking the button opens one of several new pages, depending on which box/boxes are checked. All of that works.

I want to limit the number of boxes checked to 2 per column. (Later I hope to limit it to 1/column for the second two columns, but right now I can't limit it at all.) I can't make that work. What I'm trying doesn't interfere with the rest of the code, but it still allows unlimited checking.

I'm including a dummy script below; the real script has other options for the choices and the URL results, plus more styling detail, but otherwise matches this.

**What I've tried:** the JQuery bit of the code is yoinked from someone online, but I follow the logic. I've tried running the code with that portion included in different parts of the whole; I'm not sure where it should go, but nothing has worked.

I'm wondering if something is wrong with (1) my syntax, or (2) how I'm calling/structuring the JQuery part of the code within the rest. I'm doing this in Chrome, FWIW.

Thank you--I really appreciate any help!

Simplified example code:

```
<head>
<meta name="scheduler" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
  body {font-family:arial; background-color:white; line-height: 1.15;}

/*Handles schedule options button - how it looks, what it does when hovered over*/
#schedbutton{
background-color:#f8b019; 
}

/*Columns: 3 equal*/
.column{
 float: left;
 width: 33.33%;
 .padding: 10px;
 }  

.row:after{
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

/*Responsive layout - columns will stack for narrow screens*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
width: 100%;
}
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Schedule SME Phone Support</h1>
<p><b>Directions:</b> Directions will go here.</p>

<!--divides the rest into columns-->

<div class="row">
 <div class="column" style="background-color:white;">

 <h2>Support Group A</h2>
 <p>Choose one or two main topics.</p>
 <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
   <input type="checkbox" id="apple"> Apple<br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="asteroid"> Asteroid<br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="ambulance"> Ambulance<br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="animal"> Animal<br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="allergy"> Allergy<br>
  </form>

</div>

<div class="column" style="background-color:white"> <!--2nd column-->

<h2>Support Group B</h2>
<p>Choose one main topic.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" id="brains">Brains<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="brawn">Brawn<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="bluetooth">Bluetooth<br>
</form>
</div>

<div class="column" style="background-color:white;"><!--3rd column-->
<h2>Support Group C</h2>
<p>Choose one main topic.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" id="cake">Cake<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="canvas">Canvas<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="copper">Copper<br>
</form>
</div>

<!--Button to click, which triggers script based on form selections-->

<br>
<button id=schedbutton onclick="myFunction()">See Scheduling Options</button>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
/*for some reason, still cannot make this work*/
/*testing to try and limit number of ckboxes per group checked*/
$('.column:checkbox').change(function () {
var $cs = $(this).closest('.column').find(':checkbox:checked');
if ($cs.length > 2) {
this.checked = false;
}
});
</script>



<!--Script to make the button actually do what we want-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(){

/*NB: can't make alert boxes work in New Google Sites, possibly due to iframe limitations?*/
/*Anyhow: if there IS a way to make them work, use that as the fallback instead of a separate "nope" page.*/

if (document.getElementById("apple").checked == true) {

window.open('http://www.washingtonpost.com');
} else if (document.getElementById("asteroid").checked == true) {

window.open('http://www.theonion.com');
}
else {
window.open('http://www.google.com');
}
/*obviously, add in other branches for other options, probably as switch/case not a bunch of if/then*/
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<script>` that has a `src=` attribute will not run code that is between the tags, so you have to separate them out to two different scripts:

Example

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.column:checkbox').change(function () {
 /* rest of your code */
});
</script>
```

So that is one reason your jQuery code was not working.

The other is you are using the wrong selector: `.column:checkbox` selects checkboxes that have a class of `column`, eg `<input type="checkbox" class="column">`.

You want to select checkboxes within a element with class `column` and for  that you want to put a space between `column` and `:checkbox`. The separation indicates ones a parent element while the other is a some child element:

```
$('.column :checkbox')
```

Demo

```js
$('.column :checkbox').change(function() {
  var $cs = $(this).closest('.column').find(':checkbox:checked');
  if ($cs.length > 2) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

#schedbutton {
  background-color: #f8b019;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  .padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:white;">

      <h2>Support Group A</h2>
      <p>Choose one or two main topics.</p>
      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" id="apple"> Apple<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="asteroid"> Asteroid<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ambulance"> Ambulance<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="animal"> Animal<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="allergy"> Allergy<br>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:white">
      <!--2nd column-->

      <h2>Support Group B</h2>
      <p>Choose one main topic.</p>

      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" id="brains">Brains<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="brawn">Brawn<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bluetooth">Bluetooth<br>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:white;">
      <!--3rd column-->
      <h2>Support Group C</h2>
      <p>Choose one main topic.</p>

      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cake">Cake<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="canvas">Canvas<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="copper">Copper<br>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I see where you also moved the `src=` attribute line to just before the row/column structuring, which I think was important. With that, and with the actual jQuery script after the form setup, it's great.

Comment: Actually that's just to how Stackoverflow's stacksnippets thing injects a library option you select (at the top of the code). You could keep it right above the other script and would have worked the same. But the actual jQuery code `$().change()` does have to come after (or put in a ready event) so that it runs after the elements are in the DOM, otherwise you would experience this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element